# Access VBA7 and Win64 Conditional Compiler constant through Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, vbscript, ms-office

I have software that can run either a VBS or Powershell script on a targeted endpoint (these are the only options). I want to use this software to determine whether the version of MS Office that is installed is x64 or x86. There are registry keys that can be an indicator but in testing they have not been consistent.

I found this [VBA constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview) that I think will be a better indicator. The problem is that I cannot access this value through a VBS script on the endpoint since it's VBA. I've heard that Powershell can use VBA constants, how would I go about retrieving the Win64 constant value? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: `const fred = 1`. VBScript uses late binding. Constants aren't available from **the type library**. You have to type with a keyboard instead.

Comment: But can you access those constants through Powershell somehow?

Comment: By typing them, anywhere.